# Сравнение двух файлов онлайн?

Tags: javascript, diff

Ищу программу для вставки на свой сайт или онлайн сервис, который позволит передавать 2 текста (программно) и сравнить их различия. То есть нужно сравнение версий кода.

Как тут https://www.diffchecker.com/

Максимально простую и не перегруженную другим функционалом. Только сравнение кода.

Comment: например: [Mergely](http://www.mergely.com/doc)

Comment: на чем сайт написан какой код сравнивать? https://git.zx2c4.com/cgit/